# How to play Minecraft together with an iPad and an iPod?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an iPad and my sister has an iPod, my username shows up on her iPod, but when she clicks it, it says "outdated server".

We're on the same network/wifi and I've followed all the other different steps, but nothing works.

Comment: They have to be the same version of minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Minecraft gives you this error message is because one of the devices is using an older version of Minecraft PE than the other. Sometimes it does not matter as much (as with versions 1.0.3 and 1.0.4), others, such as with big updates (0.16.0 and 1.0) are not cross compatible because of major changes to the game. 
Try updating. Go to the App Store on both devices and go to the updates tab. Then update whichever one that needs to be updated. Then try it again. It should work.